# java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getFlash

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, heroku, nullpointerexception

I had created a simple JSF2.0 app and it runs fine in my computer, but when I try to run it in Heroku, I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /login.xhtml. Reason:

    Server Error

Caused by:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getFlash(ELFlash.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getELFlash(ELFlash.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.doPostPhaseActions(ELFlash.java:722)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:940)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:874)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:565)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

So, any solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Mojarra version is that? The method `ELFlash#getELFlash()` doesn't exist in 2.0.0 until with the current 2.1.4.

Comment: Hi. I was using 2.0.0-b13, then i tried with 2.1.4 but i got another error. Finally i changed to MyFaces and it works, except it can't read the annotations (!?), i have to add every managed bean/propery to the faces-config.xml.

In any case it works here in mt computer, but not in Heroku.
I think the problem is the dependencies, I'm using Maven 3.0.3. What's the correct dependencies for jsf?

Comment: Mojarra 2.1.x requires Servlet 3.0. It's not clear what Jetty version you're using and which servlet version your `web.xml` is declared to, but if it's Servlet 2.5, you need Mojarra 2.0.x (currently latest is 2.0.6). Dependencies are at least Servlet 2.5 (provided by container) and JSTL 1.2 (may or may not be provided by container, I believe Jetty doesn't, but Heroku may do). See also the requirements list http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.6/releasenotes.html.

Comment: Thanks! now it worked with 2.0.6, but the problem with annotations persists in Heroku.

I got this error:
[code]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @15,55 value="#{user.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
...
[/code]

Comment: my class:
`
@ManagedBean(name="user")
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String password;
    ...// getter, setters
}
`

it only works if I put the managed beans and properties in the faces-config.xml. And the jetty version is 7.5.1.v20110908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getFlash(ELFlash.java:93)
>     at com.sun.faces.context.flash.ELFlash.getELFlash(ELFlash.java:124)
> ```

I don't recognize the `ELFlash#getELFlash()` method as part of recent Mojarra implementations. Perhaps you're using a very early 2.0.0 implementation which has a bug related to this. Upgrading to the latest should fix this problem.

---

> *but the problem with annotations persists in Heroku*
>
> ```
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @15,55 value="#{user.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'user' resolved to null 
>     at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100‌​) 
>     at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(Html‌​BasicInputRenderer.java:95)
> ```

JSF2 annotations will fail if your `faces-config.xml` is not properly declared conform JSF2 specification. Make sure that the `<faces-config>` root declaration look like this:

```xml
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- config here -->

</faces-config>
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem wasn't the faces-config.xml. 
But I solved the problem with this:
http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.com/2009/12/running-jsf-2-on-embedded-jetty.html

Comment: We're aware of this problem when using embedded web servers. I wish JSF and other frameworks would find better ways of looking for annotation classes. Another solution is to build to a war file and run it with jetty-runner. But it's less ideal.